# Display Clicked Item with Knockoutjs

Tags: c#, .net, knockout.js

I am trying to display information about the selected item in a list as well as highlight the row that is selected.  This is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/blankasaurus/qUydu/6/

1) When I try to set the `CurrentDisplayThing = item` it doesn't do what I want it to do (which is update the Display div with the selected item).  I also tried `$.extend(CurrentDisplayThing, item);`  Am I going to have to set each property individually or something?  I have about 30 of them on my real project.

2) The other thing i wanted to figure out is how to go about highlighting the row that I just clicked the proper way using Knockout.

PS: For what I am actually doing I am using the **mapping plug-in** and both `Things` and `CurrentDisplayThing` are coming from my .NET model I pass in.  I am assuming what I have in JS Fiddle mirrors the way mapping would set this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that solves both problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/6FCEe/

1) The selected item property is actually an observable (which is a function). So the value must be passed into the observable function like this:

```
self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
```

2) Highlighting the row can be done through the css binding in Knockout. The css binding accepts an object with the name of the css class (ex: selected) and an expression (ex: isSelected). In the example below, when isSelected is true, the class will be applied, otherwise it is removed.

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.selectThing, css: { selected: isSelected} ">
```

Check the fiddle out for the full example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign Knockout observables using code like

```
CurrentDisplayThing = item
```

And you can't `$.extend` them either, because in the end that does assignments too.

Instead you have to use the function syntax:

```
self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
```

Similarly you have to use the function syntax when accessing:

```
self.model.CurrentDisplayThing().ID
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HUjau/1/