# Highlight selected row using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

With reference to below question asked in stackoverflow

[Display clicked item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838132/display-clicked-item-with-knockoutjs)

I have modified the fiddle created by john papa. Here is my updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/31/

I have added New button and clicking on it i push new record.In click event of New button i have added below code

```
 this.NewDetail = function(){
    self.model.Things.push(new Thing(4, "Thing 4", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing)               
        );
    self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
  };
```

But the new row doesnt show as higlighted. What should i do to make it highlighted. The new row added should be shown as higlighted in yellow color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the New button you will see the following error in your browser javascript console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined

Because you don't have `item` in your method. In your case the `item` should be the newly created `Thing` so store it in a variable which you can name `item` and it will work fine.

```
this.NewDetail = function(){
    var item = new Thing(4, "Thing 4", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing);
    self.model.Things.push(item);
    self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
  };
```

Here is an updated [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/33/).

Comment: This works fine. Many thanks for it. I have one more scenario like on click on New button i will just create blank row and will push record only when user click on Update button. How can i handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Just trivial bug

```
this.NewDetail = function(){
        var item = new Thing(4, "Thing 4", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing);
        self.model.Things.push(item);
        self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
      };
```

Comment: Many thanks
This works fine. Many thanks for it. I have one more scenario like on click on New button i will just create blank row and will push record only when user click on Update button. How can i handle this scenario?