# Highlight rows with click in knockout js, and pass data to new array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a web service that passes a list of customers with other data. I would like to be able to click on multiple customers, adding them to an array that I'll use elsewhere. Clicking on them again will remove them from the array.

Similar in some aspects to this solution:

[Highlight selected row using knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212350/highlight-selected-row-using-knockout)

If someone could explain what the computed value is comparing to and how that works, I think I might be able to get the rest on my own:

```
self.isSelected = ko.computed(function() {
    return selected() === self;            
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/33/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to setup an observable property and add/remove from the array when value changes. Or just check which one is selected at any point in time. Let me create a sample in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/55/

```
Thing = function(id, name, selected) {

    var self = this;
    self.ID = id, 
    self.Name = name, 
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.isSelected.subscribe(function (selected){
        if (selected){
            // Add to array
        } else {
            // Remove from array
        }
    });
};
```

And update onClick event to be:

```
self.selectThing = function(item) {
    item.isSelected(!item.isSelected());
};
```