# Knockout: Selecting row programmatically and setting focus during data entry

Tags: knockout.js

Please check the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yv8h8hca/1/

Source post:
[Highlight selected row using knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212350/highlight-selected-row-using-knockout)

The following already happens:

1. Row is selected on the  element.
2. Row can be updated.
3. Row can be added to the array.

I would like users to be able to fill out data in a row, and then after pressing the Update button to automatically select the new row (with the existing yellow background) and set focus on the ID column setting it ready for editing.

I want to avoid having users to click on the new row with the mouse in order to select it.

HTML:

```
<table class="defaultGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: NewDetail">New</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Things">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectThing, css: { selected: isSelected} ">
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: ID">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button style="width:60px" data-bind="click: $parent.UpdateDetail">Update</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button style="width:64px" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveDetail">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    Thing = function (id, name, selected) {

        var self = this;
        self.ID = id,
        self.Name = name,
        self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
            return selected() === self;

        });
    };

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.model = {};
        self.model.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observable();
        self.model.Things = ko.observableArray(
        [
        new Thing(1, "Thing 1", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing),
        new Thing(2, "Thing 2", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing),
        new Thing(3, "Thing 3", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing)]);
        self.selectThing = function (item) {
            self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
        };

        this.NewDetail = function () {
            var item = new Thing(4, "Thing 4", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing);
            self.model.Things.push(item);
            self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
        };

        // Update NVD
        this.UpdateDetail = function (entry) {
            // code to update detail....

            // Now, create new row for next input

            var item = new Thing(entry.ID + 1, "", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing);
            self.model.Things.push(item);
            self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
        };

        self.RemoveDetail = function (entry) {
            self.model.Things.remove(entry);
        };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

Comment: Why is "Update" adding a new row?

Comment: This is meant to be fast data entry. Users may have to type hundreds of lines. So, after you update the current row we set up data entry for the next row. I want to avoid using the mouse here as much as possible. I'm aware of the Add New button on the form, but again, it would be nice to create new rows as you type  to keep the data entry flow.

Comment: The problem I currently have is that unless you click on a row with the mouse I cannot select it. I would like to be able to select a row after creating it as a result of pressing the Update button.

Answer (score 0):

To select the new row I had to stop the row click event from bubbling up otherwise it would select the row where the Save button was clicked.

```
<td><button style="width:60px" data-bind="event: {click : $parent.Detail }, clickBubble: false">Save</button></td>
```

To set the edit mode I set the hasfocus data-bind attribute:

```
<td><input type="text" class="nvd" data-bind="value: ID, hasfocus: isNew"></td>
```